# Libgdx Timer.stop() not working?

Tags: timer, libgdx

I have added a Timer to my game and it works fine but the problem I am facing now is the Timer .stop() method does not seem to work for me. I would like to reset the timer everytime the user click an option but it seem that the timer. stop method is not working.

May I ask what have I not done ?

this is my timer method. I am using Timer.instance.stop() to stop the timer.

```
public void timer(){
    System.out.println("Timer started!!!");
    Timer.schedule(new Task(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Timer UP!!!");

            nextWord(game.getterSetter.getCategoryItem(),
                    game.getterSetter.getCategory());
        }
    }, gametime);

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to reset every thing then just use

**Timer.instance().clear();**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset every thing then just use

```
Timer.clear();
```

Comment: Hi , I tried using timer.clear() as well but it is not working too.